# Choose Return Type

Tags: c#, .net, math, return-value

Is there a way to choose the return value in a function or method?
My idea was to have an extra parameter to choose the return value.

```
public object test(int test, System type)
{

    return type.parse(test);
}
```

Comment: Generics might work, if you know the type you expect back.  `public T test<T>(int test);`.

Comment: What you mean in "choose the return value"? Choose something instead of "object" or choose way to return other types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static T ChangeType<T>(int test)
{
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(test, typeof(T));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as following

```
public T test<T>(int test)
    {

        return return (T)Convert.ChangeType(test, typeof(T));
    }
```

Comment: This is not compile with error "Cannot convert type 'int' to 'T'". We need use Convert.ChangeType instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35662420/675632

Comment: @DmitryRazumikhin Let me figure it out

Comment: @DmitryRazumikhin lets check it again it should work now

Answer (score 0):

You want to declare your method to return a [Generic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) type

```
    public object TestGenericMethod<T>(int test)
    {
        T result = SomeMethodThatReturnsTheTypeYouExpect(test);
        return result;
    }
```

You would call it like this:

```
        int myParam = 0;
        string myObject = TestGenericMethod<string>(myParam);
```